# How add or subtract number within Apache Maven

Tags: maven

Let's say for example that my POM.xml has a variable like this:

```
<lab.ver>20</lab.ver>
```

how can I achieve subtract i.e. ${lab.ver} - 1 and assign this to a new variable; i.e. ${lab.previousver}

Ex:

```
<lab.previousver>${lab.ver}-1</lab.previousver>
```

Thanks,

Carlos M.

Comment: No u can not. Why u need this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by maven by default, but You could write a plugin that takes this expression and sets maven property at runtime during initialization pahse